# How I call a library defined globally in a particuler page , not in every page : Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

Excuse Me, I defined a library in app/start/global.php

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/trunk/index.php', <----- MY CUSTOM LIBRARY 

));
```

I want to load or call this library only in a particular page. Now it is working for every page. Need a help ..

Comment: @Sandesh: when suggesting edits, please ensure your changes make the post easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. In the majority of edits, your changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability. Take a look at the [editing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes !! I found the solution in little bit different approach.

I add it in routes.php instead of global.php

```
Route::get('/calender', function()
{
    $c = require app_path().'/trunk/index.php';

    return View::make('calender')->with('c', $c);
});
```

and add this in calender.blade.php

```
<h1><?php echo "{$c}"; ?></h1>
```